# Tapku Calendar - How to implement List, Day and Month view using Tapku Calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, tapku

i want to implement a calendar application like Month View,Day View and Week View using Tapku library for my iPhone application.MonthView already there.So i am concentrating Day and week view.If anybody having any idea for this,Please let me know?

Please let me know How to start for implementing Day and MonthView.

Thanks in Advance,
Jayaprakash S

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this GitHub link to see the implementation of a calendar application like Month View,Day View and Week View using Tapku library.

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/pull/57/files

Alternatively you can try MACalendarUI project which offers calendar user interface for iPhone applications.

https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui